# Micro SD card reader will only open SD card in read-only mode (SD card can write via other readers)

Tags: sd-card

I have a Kingston MobileLite SD card reader, which I've used for years. Suddenly it stopped being able to write to SD cards. I verified with another reader that I can in fact write to the cards. However, it seems to be able to read from the cards fine. I'm hoping it isn't just dead hardware at this point, so I thought I'd ask here.

Yes I've read the myriads of SD card read-only questions - this is a new one. It certainly isn't the SD card (hardware switch or software bit). Its the reader itself.

Answer (score 0):

Check for driver update in Device Manager, or using [Snappy Driver Installer](https://sdi-tool.org/).